# How to mimic (single parameter) overload resolution rules in own code?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an arbitrary **object instance** which may implement interfaces and/or inherit from a type hierarchy.

And I have a **set of workers** (injected by DI) which accept a single input parameter.

I can reduce both to a single input `System.Type` and an array of `System.Type` as candidates.

Does there exist some framework code (or maybe a function in a Roslyn NuGet Package) which applies the same rules as overload resolution would do, and either returns a matching type of the given set or an ambiguous-exception?

For example if my instance is of type `DirectoryInfo` then a worker designed for `FileSystemInfo` (base class of `DirectoryInfo`) could be used, but only if not a worker for `DirectoryInfo`type exists.

*Of course I could walk down the BaseTypes hierarchy, but I also want to consider interfaces (including co(ntra)variance). I really don't want to reinvent that wheel and then frustrate other developers because I created my own personal ruleset.*

Comment: I don't know built-in version of that but i would simply list the hierarchy of the instance and find the first implemented worker. If they were mapped to a dictionary by type it would be very fast and easy

Comment: @Franck I'm already doing this since this is the simpliest solution to do. But I also want to map a `List<DirectoryInfo>` instance to a worker accepting `IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>`.

Comment: That is much more complicated. You need to assign a priority to each with some sort of weight. If you have the following 2 worker `List<DirectoryInfo>`, `IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>` and the type you are looking at is `IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>` which one would you pick ?

Comment: @Franck If possible I want the very same behavior as the compiler would apply when resolving overloads.

Comment: I am "guessing" that when dealing with these case they take `IEnumerable` over `List` and for class they take `Derived` over `Base`. As for class that implement `ICollection` i have no clue where that would stand nor `Generics`.

Comment: @springy76 did you then resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

A set of `Type` extension methods you may found useful in your case:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAssignableToType(this Type derivedType, Type baseType)
    {
        bool retVal = baseType.IsAssignableFrom(derivedType) ||
                      (baseType.IsGenericType && derivedType.IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType)) ||
                      (baseType.IsInterface && (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(derivedType)?.IsAssignableToType(baseType) ?? false));
        return retVal;
    }

    private static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(this Type derivedType, Type genericBaseType)
    {
        var interfaceTypes = derivedType.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (var it in interfaceTypes)
        {
            if (it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericBaseType)
                return true;
        }

        if (derivedType.IsGenericType && derivedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericBaseType)
            return true;

        Type baseType = derivedType.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null) return false;

        return IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericBaseType);
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
var isWorkerSuitableForObj = yourObjectInstance.GetType().IsAssignableToType(yourWorkerType)
```

This also works with generics and even with generic open types (e.g. `IEnumerable<>`).

Comment: This is going in the right direction, but I need to find the best fit of a set of candidates (or throw an ambiguous-exception if there is no "best").

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. Maybe you can generate a tree of workers by testing which one **IsAssignableTo** which one, so you have a **score** for each one.

Comment: For example, the score of a `IEnumerable<>` worker would be less then the score of a `List<>` worker, because `typeof(List<>).IsAssignableToType(typeof(IEnumerable<>))`